# Unable to edit the content of a mounted ext2 image

Tags: mount, android, ext2

I have an image (from an Android phone) for which `file` gave the following info:

```
file vendor-rw.img 
vendor-rw.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=64d47c8e-6f74-54ea-bbe7-ce29a05c4b04, volume name "vendor" (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

I can successfully mount image with the following command in `Ubuntu 20 x64`:

```
sudo mount -o loop,rw -t ext4 vendor-rw.img tmp/
```

Obviously the image is not sparse but I cannot edit the content of the mounted drive;

What is the problem?

**Solved**!:
The owner of the mounted point was `root` and I was running operations on the drive (mkdir for example) as non-root user.

Comment: It might help to post the error message you get when you try to write to the filesystem.

Comment: For any operation (for example creating a folder in the mounted drive) it says: Permission denied.

Comment: Add the permissions and ownership of the data that you are trying to modify and the user that is trying to modify the data to the question.

Comment: @NasirRiley running `mkdir` with `sudo`, created a folder in the drive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious. sorry guys.

Comment: Edit the question and add it there. Don't post it in the comments. Add the permissions and owners.

Comment: What should I do with this post? Delete it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just add the information to the question.

Comment: Looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great. Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of not having sufficient permissions. The owner of the mounted point was `root` and I was running operations on the drive (`mkdir` for example) as non-root user.

Running operations (on the mounted drive) with `root` privileges solved the problem.